# SDL Pong Movement Bug

Tags: c++, c++14, sdl-2

The problem with my code is that I am making a pong game in SDL 2.0 in c++. I did everything until creating the movement. When the player paddle moves, it leaves behind a trail in the same color as the paddle. I watched some videos on YouTube, but when they do the movement it's nice and clear and for me to fix this but I need to recolor the background every time the player moves, which makes it being all flashy and if I hold the button I don't see the paddle at all.

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include<windows.h>

#define width 800
#define height 600

using namespace std;


bool run = true;



class Player{
private:
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
SDL_Surface* Screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
Uint32 screen_color = SDL_MapRGB(Screen->format, 0, 0, 0);
Uint32 In_game_RGB = SDL_MapRGB(Screen->format, 255, 255, 255);

SDL_Rect Pl;
SDL_Rect AI;
SDL_Rect Ball;
SDL_Rect ClearP;
SDL_Rect ClearAI;

public:
Player(){
//Player parameters
Pl.x = 60;Pl.y = 225;Pl.w = 25;Pl.h = 200;
//AI parameters
AI.x = 720;AI.y = 225;AI.w = 25;AI.h = 200;
//Ball parameters
Ball.x = width/2;Ball.y = height/2+10;Ball.w = 25;Ball.h = 25;
//Recoloring parameters
ClearP.x = 0;ClearP.y = 0; ClearP.w = 375;ClearP.h = height;
ClearAI.x = 425;ClearAI.y = 0;ClearAI.w = 375;ClearAI.h = height;
//Make the screen color black
SDL_FillRect(Screen, NULL, screen_color);
}

void scrUpdate(){
 SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

}
void drawPlayer(){
SDL_FillRect(Screen, &Pl, In_game_RGB);
}
void drawComputer(){
SDL_FillRect(Screen, &AI, In_game_RGB);
}
void ball(){
SDL_FillRect(Screen, &Ball, In_game_RGB);
}

void Movement(){

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
Pl.y += 2;
SDL_FillRect(Screen,&ClearP,screen_color);
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
SDL_FillRect(Screen,&ClearP,screen_color);
Pl.y -= 2;
}
}
};

void EventCheck(){
SDL_Event event;
if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
run = false;
}
}
}



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
Player Play;
//Player Computer();

while(run){
Play.scrUpdate();
Play.drawPlayer();
Play.drawComputer();
Play.ball();
Play.Movement();
EventCheck();

}

SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to clear viewport (e.g. `SDL_RenderClear`), but I suppose you already figured that. If you say you have flickering but others don't - then most likely you're doing something they don't; since no code was shown, only you could theoretically know what that is.

Comment: the only thing the others are doing differently is that they are using an older sdl version but I never tried SDL_RenderClear I will try it. Thanks

Comment: also I added the code I am using you can try it yourself to see if you have the same result. Just spam the up arrow key so you can actually see the player paddle. DO NOT HOLD IT

Comment: @PlamenTsanev well you don't use SDL renderer so no renderclear for you. You're doing something similar with FillRect though. Flicker happens because you draw rectangle, then if event happens erase it, then display it on screen - after that, you display nothing (what was drawn now erased), and will only be drawn on next frame, if button is not held. You should change order of things - first check event and erase/move (erasing phase is arguably could/should be removed, but that's beside the point), then draw.

Comment: thanks for that but I managed to modify my code to use a renderer, and it turned out to be much much more smoother. But now I have a problem. When I make the ball to move when the game starts duo to the while look ven if it moves 1 pixel per frame I cant even see it go, but I am scared that if I make the framerate lower the player movement would go much slower and it wouldnt look that good.

Comment: @PlamenTsanev sorry I don't understand you at all. What is your problem and what is your actual question?

Answer (score -1):

It would help to show some code or an example of what you have been doing, or a link to one of the videos you have been watching:
[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVk7N8eUjsc&list=PLrNC1KDUyzSqgFJUWzdBar2tAEMu6QpaO)

but I suggest taking a look at:
`screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);` and `SDL_Flip(screen)` as those have to do with screen buffering and drawing.

Another possibilty is that you are running an outdated version of SDL, or an incompatible one with your current system.

To be able to give a more complete and proper answer, I'd highly suggest adding more information about your code, screenshots of results and your version of SDL and operating system.

Also, you said it was flashy when you hold the paddle. I think it must be that you are performing your logic to move the paddle and you redraw the paddle once it's still. If you are redrawing the entire screen constantly, consider double buffering.

Comment: I don't think SDL 2 has `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.

Comment: I am using SDL 2 and windows 10 so I cant use SDL_SetVideoMode

Comment: welp if Stack Overflow actually had a more understandable code paste system I would like to show you the code. If you have an email or something I can send it to you